# Policies for keeping/stripping class name prefixes when interfacing to C libraries

Tags: python, naming-conventions, naming

I have C library that exposes types like `SkiUser` and `SkiContact`, and has lots of functions like `SkiUserLogin()` and `SkiUserLogout()` that accept a pointer to relevant type as their first argument.

I would like to create Python/Cython interface for this library, and it seems natural that `SkiUserLogin()` should become `login()` method of `SkiUser` object.

The question is — given that every type name starts with `Ski`, should I keep this prefix in my Python classes, so I have this:

```
from ski import SkiUser
user = SkiUser(...)
user.login()
```

Or should I strip it and only keep it in the name of package?

```
import ski
user = ski.User(...)
user.login()
```

Are there any recommendations on which approach to use and why?

Answer (score 0):

I would remove `Ski` from type names. If every type and function has the same prefix, it's probably meant as a namespace.

Also, you should use `import ski` and not other variants. There is a good explanation in [The Hitch Hiker's Guide to Python](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/#modules) why you should do so:

> It is possible to simulate the more standard behavior by using a
>   special syntax of the import statement: `from modu import *`. This is
>   generally considered bad practice. **Using `import *` makes code harder to
>   read and makes dependencies less compartmentalized.**
>
> Using `from modu import func` is a way to pinpoint the function you want
>   to import and put it in the global namespace. While much less harmful
>   than `import *` because it shows explicitly what is imported in the
>   global namespace, its only advantage over a simpler `import modu` is
>   that it will save a little typing.
>
> **Very bad**

```
[...]
from modu import *
[...]
x = sqrt(4)  # Is sqrt part of modu? A builtin? Defined above?
```

> **Better**

```
from modu import sqrt
[...]
x = sqrt(4)  # sqrt may be part of modu, if not redefined in between
```

> **Best**

```
import modu
[...]
x = modu.sqrt(4)  # sqrt is visibly part of modu's
```

Comment: While I can agree with short and concise `modu.sqrt`, how about not so beautiful, but real `selenium.webdriver.common.keys.Keys`?

Comment: For such a case, I'd recommend to use an alias, like `import selenium.webdriver.common.keys as skeys`, then you can write `skeys.Keys`.